# PartialEq and PartialOrd impls not returning correct output

Tags: rust

I have implemented `PartialEq` and `PartialOrd` for my struct so I can create `BTreeSet`s of these structs using some custom logic: a struct is equal if the name field in the struct is equal to the name field of another struct. When I lookup if a struct is in this set, it only returns true if the entire struct is in the set not just the name field. How can I fix this so that both asserts return true?

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e9a4245723d72bc7b4a6c21dfce40af9)

```
use std::cmp::Ordering;
use std::collections::BTreeSet;


#[derive(Debug, Eq, Hash, Ord)]
struct Obj {
    name: String,
    count: i64,
}

impl PartialEq for Obj {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self.name == other.name
    }
}

impl PartialOrd for Obj {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Option<Ordering> {
        Some(self.name.cmp(&other.name))
    }
}

fn vec_to_set(v: &[&str]) -> BTreeSet<Obj> {
    let hs: BTreeSet<Obj> = v
        .iter()
        .map(|d| {
            let mut count = 1;
            if d.to_string() == "C".to_string() {
                count = 2;
            };

            Obj {
                name: d.to_string(),
                count,
            }
        })
        .collect();
    hs
}

fn main() {
    let v = vec!["A", "B", "C", "A"];

    let hs = vec_to_set(&v);
    let t1 = Obj {
        name: "A".to_string(),
        count: 1,
    };
    let t2 = Obj {
        name: "A".to_string(),
        count: 10,
    };
    assert!(hs.contains(&t1));  // true
    assert!(hs.contains(&t2));  // false
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot manually implement `PartialOrd` or `PartialEq` and derive `Ord`. The different implementations must agree with each other, and the default generated `Ord` implementation is different from your manual implementations.

If you replace `#[derive(Ord)]` with

```rust
impl Ord for Obj {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Ordering {
        self.name.cmp(&other.name)
    }
}
```

your program works as expected.

You however can derive `Eq` when deriving `PartialEq`, because `Eq` is just a marker trait, so its derived implementation can't contradict yours.

---

The derived implementation for `Hash` *also* disagrees with the manual implementation for `PartialEq`. `BTreeSet` doesn't use `Hash`, but `HashMap` and `HashSet` do, and they would misbehave too with the derived `Hash` impl.

Comment: Seems like a serious pitfall that you can incompatibly derive  traits when the underlying "operational" trait is manually implemented. Though at least Clippy triggers a hard error (score one for clippy!)

Comment: There is no “underlying "operational" trait”, `Ord` can’t be implemented in terms of `PartialOrd`. Same for `PartialEq`, `Hash` et al. And the implementations can be arbitrarily complex so the compiler can’t prove that the implementations are compatible with each other. Clippy’s lint is a best effort “this probably doesn’t make sense” lint. If you think this is too manual, there are crates (eg. derivative, of which I’m the author) that provide smarter `derive` macros than the standard ones, and in particular can skip fields.

Comment: @mccarton that seems obviously untrue since `Eq` is literally just a marker trait over `PartialEq`. The case of `Ord` is more complicated and it doesn't make much sense to define `Ord` in terms of `PartialOrd` when you could do the opposite, but technically nothing precludes doing that. But my question was rather more that `PartialOrd` is a precondition to deriving `Ord`. If a derived `Ord` is necessarily incompatible with an implemented `PartialOrd`, it stands to reason that this case *should be a compilation error*.

Comment: Your manually implemented `PartialOrd` could do the same thing as the derived `Ord`, and thus be compatible, so I don't think it should be completely forbidden.  Maybe you wanted to add a `println!()` to debug something.